# python no file or directory error removing a entry point (setup.py)

Tags: python, setup.py

I installed a custom entry point using `setup.py`

`pip install --editable path_to_setup.py`

This is my `setup.py`

```
 from setuptools import setup     
 setup(
        name="sample",
        version="0.1",
        py_modules=["sample"],
        entry_points="""
            [console_scripts]
            sample=sample:fun 
        """,
    )
```

now when I run sample, fun() runs, then i tried to remove command sample, so i deleted the `sample.exe` and some other files in python lib files .Now when i run sample i get

> /usr/local/bin/sample: No such file or directory

how to go clean everything and get back to original state where running sample gave "command not found"

Comment: What operation system do you use?

Comment: @Reznik am using macOs

Comment: Well you just delete `sample`, so its not there anymore, jsut install the package again